# Restrict data user wise in PowerBI Report Server

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a power BI report like as imported(using import connection) from a sql server-

[image: Dataset]

User can be Employee or Manager. So, if any one login from Employeeemail or ManagerEmail, then only, respective data should show to him/her. ALso, the slicers should show accordingly. Suppose a Manager logs in , then slicer whill show the employeeemail who are under the manager. or vice-versa.

[image]

Comment: This is called row level security and it's a built in and fabulous feature in Power BI.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I am trying with row level security , Where I am giving condition as [mangeremail] = userprincipalname() || [employeeemail] = userprincipalname() into manage roles. However, it is not working when users try to access the report into report server. They are able to see all records.
Note : @gmail.com is just a sample, actually it has company domain only.

Comment: You created a security role in Desktop when you added that DAX statement comparing fields to USERPRINCIPALNAME().  Have you added all report viewers to that role in PowerBI service?  Hopefully there is an AD group that contains all the users.  Also note that users with edit permissions on the workspace will not be affected by RLS.  Before making the report generally available, be sure to test it as different users who should and shouldn't be able to see different sets of records.  The article has instructions for this kind of impersonation.